# Sublime Text 2 / Sublime Text 3 bring back unsaved files on osx

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In sublime I know even if you don't save the changes in a file later one you can start from where you left off. I opened a new tab in sublime and closed the application before I save my file. Does sublime save a temp file somewhere in the computer (I am using MAC OSx)

Comment: It must save it in a temp file isn't it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 stores the files in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings`, in the `.sublime_session` files that are located there.

The contents of those files are a large JSON blob that contains the individual tab contents.  Search in the file for the file name / tab name / a key word in the document and you should be able to get what you need.

---

For Sublime Text 3, use the following path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session
```

Credit to: [eebbesen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317829/eebbesen)

Comment: Yes! I've restored unsaved closed file data. There is json there you may find last version of the file by file name.

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session worked for me with SublimeText3.

Comment: For Sublime 3.2.2, found it at /Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session.

Comment: if it is not in the default installation folder (~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session), locate it macos terminal: find . -name "Session.sublime_session"

Answer (score 14):

I know it's a late answer but here's where I found it.

**Linux**: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

**Windows**: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Settings\Session.sublime_session`

Hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Sublime Text keeps open files when you quit the application. However, if you close the tabs or project window without saving, the changes are lost.

In the former case, the files are saved in `Local/Session.sublime-session` (I'm using ST3 though, could be different in ST2!) You can open ST's packages folder from the command palette using "Browse Packages".

Comment: I copied, and then closed the sublime tab. But once I want to paste, I forget and copy another text, which overwrites my previous clipboard from sublime. Because I don't have a clipboard manager application on my macbook, it looks like I have to re-type all my previously unsaved text from the sublime application :(.

Answer (score 3):

**For Sublime Text 3**,

**Windows**: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session`

Comment: Add more info about what this is.

Answer (score 2):

For **Sublime Text 3** / **For Sublime Text 4**

If you used portable version(.zip) version then refer to
sublime_installation_folder\Data\Local\Session.sublime_session

PS: Make a backup, before replacing the file, in case, you want to revert

This gives you your unsaved files and opened files as per your recent view.