# Sublime Text 3: Recover unsaved files lost because of killed application [OSx]

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I accidentally force-closed my Sublime Text 3 using Mac's Activity Monitor and when I restarted, Sublime didn't recover all the unsaved files (~50 of them).

I went through several posts in StackOverflow as well Sublime forum, but none of them worked for me. Examples:

- [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257660/sublime-text-2-bring-back-unsaved-files-on-osx).
- [Sublime forum post1](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-recover-lost-unsaved-files/18673/5):  The requester recovered using a file in Project folder. Since I didn't have any Project open, I'm not sure where would I find that kind of a file.
- [Sublime forum post2](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/any-way-to-recover-closed-windows/15497): A reply on this post says that I'm pretty much screwed because I was not using Projects.

Anyways, I searched for all the files in my Mac with name "sublime" and found some files like the ones listed below:

```
/Users/Username/Library/Saved Application State/com.sublimetext.3.savedState/data.data
/Users/Username/Library/Saved Application State/com.sublimetext.3.savedState/window_1.data
/Users/Username/Library/Saved Application State/com.sublimetext.3.savedState/windows.plist

/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session
/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session

/Users/Username/Library/Caches/com.sublimetext.3/Cache.db
/Users/Username/Library/Caches/com.sublimetext.3/Cache.db-shm
/Users/Username/Library/Caches/com.sublimetext.3/Cache.db-wal

/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/Sublime Text_C6A04335-E900-5C09-B4A3-F203F47923E7.plist

/Users/Username/.Trash/Sublime Text (3114).app/Contents/MacOS/crash_reporter
```

"file_history" in "Session.sublime_session" does not have names of contents for any of the lost files.

I do have "hot_exit" flag set a false.

I don't know what happened this time for Sublime, otherwise it would always open those (now lost) windows and tabs upon start whenever my Mac has crashed.

I have lost a lot of important details with this(and most likely very costly) mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Rajan

Comment: Can't help with the problem, but you should set the `save_on_focus_lost` and `hot_exit` settings to `true` to avoid this happening again.

Answer (score 3):

The magic is a workable way for me.

1. Close Sublime Text 3 completely.
2. Restore this file **Auto Save
   Session.sublime_session** from **Time Machine** to the "Local"
   directory, and choose it by your latest edit and unsaved
   timestamp. 
   /Username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session
3. Reopen Sublime and the unsaved files will show into your eyes.
4. Surprise! ...and not forget to save them.